# finding critical points in families of functions

Tags: calculus

Assuming *a* and *b* are non-zero constants, for the function below, find values of *a* and *b* that ensure *f* has a critical point at (2.10)

[image]

Comment: Found. Now what?

Comment: Why is this problem difficult for you? What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried finding the derivative. I just have no idea how to go about finding what a and b are.

Comment: If you know the derivative then you know that the $ae^{-2x}=abxe^{-2x}$ equation has to be solved for x. So...